# Clear v-autocomplete as soon as a value has been selected

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm trying to do the following with the `v-autocomplete` component:

1. The user selects a value in the `v-autocomplete` component
2. As soon as a value have been selected, I save the value in a `lastModel` property
3. I want to clear the `v-autocomplete` value in order to allow the user to continue typing another value.

**Problem is: I can't clear the v-autocomplete component as soon as I select a value.**

Here is the basic markup I wrote to illustrate what I want:

```
<v-autocomplete
   v-model="model"
   :items="states"
   label="Where do you live"
   @change="modelChanged"
   ref="autocompleteComponent"
/>
```

And the JS:

```
new Vue({
    data () {
        return {
            model: null,
            lastModel: null,
            states: [
                'Alabama', 'Alaska'
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        modelChanged () {
            // We don't want lastModel to update if model is null
            if (this.model) {
                this.lastModel = this.model
            }
            this.model = null
        }
    }
})
```

So that does not work. However, if I wait one second in order to reset the model, it works:

```
new Vue({
    data () {
        return {
            model: null,
            lastModel: null,
            states: [
                'Alabama', 'Alaska'
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        modelChanged () {
            if (this.model) {
                this.lastModel = this.model
            }
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.model = null
            }, 1000)
        }
    }
})
```

However, **waiting a second is not a solution I like**, and I would love to know how to write this better, in order to make it more "native"

Here is a codepen to try it out: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyKdaZ?editors=1011

Comment: I guess just replace `setTimeout` with `this.$nextTick` :  `this.$nextTick(() => { this.model = null})`

Comment: It works, I really thought I had try that, thank you very much, you can respond to the question and I'll mark it as resolved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

replace `setTimeout` with [`this.$nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.model = null
})
```